# I have doubts about my proof of this...

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Well umm... I have a doubt if this proof is correct or I made some mistakes, especially in the second part of the proof and the extra assumptions I made. If anybody can correct me or say just that this proof is ok I would apreciate it.

Let $A, B, X$ be sets such that $A,B \subseteq X$

show

$$(B=A^{c}) \Leftrightarrow [A \cup B=X \wedge A \cap B=\emptyset]$$

*Proof*.

$\Rightarrow$)
Suppose $(B=A^{c})$ we need to show $A \cup B=X \wedge A \cap B=\emptyset$

We know that 
$$A\cup A^{c} = X \implies A\cup B = X$$
And
$$A\cap A^{c} = \emptyset \implies A\cap B = \emptyset$$

$$\therefore A\cup B = X \wedge A\cap B = \emptyset$$

$\Leftarrow$)
Suppose $A \cup B=X \wedge A \cap B=\emptyset$ we need to show $(B=A^{c})$

We know

$$A\cap A^{c} = \emptyset \implies A^{c} \subseteq B$$
So
$$B\cup A^{c} = B$$

Using this and the hypotheses:

$$B = B \cup \emptyset = B \cup (A\cap B) = (B\cup A)\cap (B\cup B) = X \cap B = X \cap (A^{c}\cup B) = (A^{c}\cup A)\cap (A^{c}\cup B) = A^{c}\cup (A\cap B) = A^{c}\cup \emptyset = A^{c} $$

$$\therefore B = A^{c}$$

$$\therefore (B=A^{c}) \Leftrightarrow [A \cup B=X \wedge A \cap B=\emptyset]$$

Answer (score 1):

I think your "if" starts off on the wrong foot; if $A\cap B=\emptyset$, then that means that $B\subseteq A^c$, not the other way around.  The fact that $A\cup B=X$ is what will give you the other side (i.e. that $A^c \subseteq B$).

Comment: How the fact that $A\cup B=X$ is going to dive the other side? I don't really get it :/

Comment: Since $A\cup B = X$, then for every element $x$ in $A^c$, since $x\in X$ and $x\notin A$, then we must have $x\in B$.